# sass function return class

Tags: css, function, sass, mixins

I have this code

```
.npt {
  ul {
    li {
      a {
        background: $red-700 !important;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to replicate this for a lot of colors, but I want to pass the color base ($red) and return this corresponding css.
I need something like this

@mixin .npt($blue); -->

```
.npt {
  ul {
    li {
      a {
        background: $blue-700 !important;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
@mixin npt($colorvariable) {
  background: $colorvariable-700 !important;
}

try this one and then include 

@include npt($blue);
```

Comment: well, but this mixin returns only background property, is it possible to return class with properties? like ul { li { a { background: $colorvariable-700 !important; }}}

Comment: try this one

@mixin npt($colorvariable) {
  ul { li { a { background: $colorvariable !important; }}}
}

Comment: well, I had already tried this solution but it did not work, now works, thanks